# Git: How to undo a rebase while the latest rebase has the same hash as the old state?

Tags: git

```
$ git reflog |head -n 3
3b6ebc8 HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
3b6ebc8 HEAD@{1}: rebase: functionabc: feature updates abc 2.0
04901d6 HEAD@{2}: rebase: functionabc: feature updates abc 1.0

$ git reflog master | head -n 9
3b6ebc8 master@{0}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 66e5e2979a3f2a9765ac65a536bd4161c7fed46c
55b3b61 master@{1}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 05148840f2550838eb1c08fc498bdaf75df84073
6095cea master@{2}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 27c460606f6cea448a4ef9a258ef923c00b3503d
7085b61 master@{3}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto b67a5829b756d9fc3d2bc260e066faac68c81f19
222e28b master@{4}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 5aaadb87a42924fb4e099d8810270cf82bc2763d
98b1ade master@{5}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 89e4555d151e4c9840c8daf66685db197b37747a
57d228b master@{6}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 9c9b9f88980b67b4d841c8397ad5436282baf50d
363f9f4 master@{7}: commit: functionabc: feature updates abc 2.0
5ab9163 master@{8}: commit: functionabc: feature updates abc 1.0

$ git log --oneline | head -n 2
3b6ebc8 functionabc: feature updates abc 2.0 (3 days ago) 
04901d6 functionabc: feature updates abc 1.0 (4 days ago)
```

Question> What is the correct way to revoke back to (3 days ago) and discard all merged files?

Comment: Your `git log` output is run through `head -n 3` but has only two lines, and your `git reflog` output is run through `head -n 10` but has only 3 lines. That implies that there are only two commits in your entire repository, in which case you can just pick the right one of the two. I suspect you may have clipped something important here and these shouldn't be the only two commits visible...

Comment: Fixed the OP. I only show parts of the log to isolate the issues. thx.

Comment: OK, next I'd suggest you show the output from `git reflog --no-abbrev master`, since the reflog for `HEAD` includes all the intermediate work during the rebase, which I believe is hiding something important here. (We still see only two commit hashes, and I imagine there's at least a third one important one.)

Comment: I have updated OP. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, but it looks like:

```
363f9f4 master@{7}: commit: functionabc: feature updates abc 2.0
```

might be the commit you want.

To find out, you can check that commit out—perhaps as a detached `HEAD`, or perhaps by assigning a branch or tag name to it—and inspect it.  But it could be any of the other `rebase finished` ones in between, or a subsequent one.

You can also run `git log` on each of the various reflog entries, but when you copy commits with `git rebase`, you copy their log messages.  (You can run `git log -p` to display non-merge commits as diffs-against-their-parents, which can help if you know something in particular to look for.)

You can run `git reflog` with the `--date=local` or `--date=iso` or similar option, so that you see the time stamp associated with each reflog entry.

Finally, in *some* cases, `ORIG_HEAD` holds the right hash ID.  For instance, if you do the following sequence of operations successfully:

```
git checkout foobranch
git rebase otherbranch
```

the name `ORIG_HEAD` *currently* holds the commit hash ID that was in `foobranch` before the rebase started.  The drawback to using `ORIG_HEAD`, and the reason reflogs were invented, is that the *next* operation that does something slightly complicated will overwrite `ORIG_HEAD` with another hash ID.

#### How to check out any one specific commit

If you want to do this as a *detached HEAD* (which is what I would use first), just run:

```
git checkout <specifier>
```

where the specifier is either the raw hash, such as `363f9f4`, or the reflog name, such as `master@{7}`.  Be aware that the brace syntax sometimes requires quoting from some shells/CLIs, e.g., `git checkout 'master@{7}'` in or, apparently, `` git checkout `master@{7}` `` in PowerShell.  (I don't use PowerShell, or Windows at all, so cannot vouch for this.)

To set a *branch or tag name* to point to a commit of your choosing, simply use the hash ID or other specifier when creating the branch or tag name.  For instance:

```
git tag i-think-this-might-be-it master@{7}
```

or:

```
git tag maybe-this-one 363f9f4
```

would create the given tag name pointing to that one specific commit.

(Once you find the correct commit, consider using `git reset --hard` to point `master` to that commit.  Then, if you've made some temporary branch and/or tag names, clean them up.)

Comment: I tried this `$ git reset --hard 363f9f4`. But now the git log doesn't show my local commit on the top anymore.

Comment: The drawback with doing a `git reset --hard` is that if you pick the wrong commit, you're now in Reflog Hell trying to find where you were just a moment ago. Fortunately for *this* case, `ORIG_HEAD` works, because `git reset` copies the old `HEAD` value to `ORIG_HEAD` before doing the reset.

Comment: If `363f9f4` is not the right commit, look at the others.

Comment: where is the ORIG_HEAD here?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `git reset` takes options and a commit specifier. `HEAD`, a hash ID, a reflog name, `ORIG_HEAD`, `master`, etc., are al commit specifiers. (Try `git rev-parse master`, `git rev-parse HEAD`, `git rev-parse HEAD@{2}`, and so on.)

Comment: `git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD` gets you the commit hash ID. `git log ORIG_HEAD` shows you the log. Remember that `git rebase` *copies* commits, so you'll have a lot of copies of commits, with different hash IDs, that otherwise look a whole lot alike. Finding which copy, using either `ORIG_HEAD` or the reflog, is what I referred to as "reflog hell" above.